# Paperclip Mongoid S3 error

Tags: amazon-s3, mongoid, paperclip

GETTING THIS ERROR WHEN UPLOADING A FILE : 
**LoadError (no such file to load -- aws-sdk (You may need to install the aws-sdk gem)):
  app/controllers/uploaded_files_controller.rb:19:in `create'**

I am using Mongo and Paperclip. I can upload files fine without using s3. However, our production server is on Heroku and so I have to use Amazon to store the files.

I've read other Stack Overflow posts about this but none address my specific issue.

1. I have restarted my server several times.  that's not it.
2. I am indeed requiring the Amazon gem in my Gemfile
3. I have done a bundle install after putting the amazon gem in ( I know its obvious, but still I had to state this )
4. I am NOT using ImageMagick.  These uploads are simple text file uploads.
5. I know that my Amazon bucket name and auth stuff is correct because I use this app to connect to other Amazon resources in a different capacity.

Can anyone help with this ? Here is my code:

```
class UploadedFile
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  require "aws/s3"

  has_mongoid_attached_file :file,
    :storage        => :s3,
    :bucket_name    => 'my-uploads',
    :path           => ':attachment/:id/:style.:extension',
    :s3_credentials => File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'amazon_s3.yml')

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer:  The gem needs to be updated.

Paperclip now requires Amazon SDK gem instead of the s3 gem.

```
gem 'aws-s3', :require => "aws/s3"
```

should be instead

```
gem 'aws-sdk',   :require => "aws-sdk"
```

Comment: whats the difference about each one? both are same, no? I'm bit confuse now.

Comment: I sincerely apologize..... I forgot to put the new game name and originally put the name of the s3 gem again.  Edited ( corrected) to point the the CORRECT NEW GEM which is..... gem 'aws-sdk',   :require => "aws-sdk"